# PowerShell AD DLs hyphen in name has 2 different formats? Escape character or something else?

Tags: powershell

I am using PowerShell to backup a list of DLs we plan to remove from AD. There are a good number of names for these with a hyphen where `Get-ADGroup "DL – Clinical` Lab Supervisors" finds the group and brings back properties, but when I try pulling this name in a foreach loop, via a variable, I get this odd error:

> Get-ADGroup : Cannot find an object with identity: 'DL � Clinical Lab Supervisors'.

Here it looks like a square, but in the ISE, it's a ? with a diamond shape around it and sometimes it's an upside down ?. Does anyone know why this happens for this character in AD? Within Excel as a csv, the dash is longer than a normal dash/hypen. I tried find replace, but then that name can't be found in AD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've processed an original list of names containing hyphens using word or excel, they might have been converted to unicode dashes by the AutoFormat feature, which is why it renders with a longer width in Excel.

Use the `-replace` operator to replace any type of dash or hyphen with an actual hyphen:

```
$ListNames = @('DL – Clinical Lab Supervisors','DL - Clinical Lab Rats')

foreach($ListName in $ListNames){
    $name = $ListName -replace '\p{Pd}','-'
    Get-ADGroup $name
}
```

the `\p{Pd}` is shorthand for the unicode character class subset "**P**unctuation, **d**ashes"

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this. So, if someone provided me a .csv from AD with these characters in the name, what format are they in coming from AD?

Comment: @MarcGel I'm not sure I understand the question. As mentioned above, if someone exported these names to CSV using PowerShell or dsquery or similar, and subsequently opened it (or copy-pasted it) in Excel and re-saved it, the AutoFormat feature in excel might have caused this unfortunate "correction"